# Setting value for Dropdown

Tags: html, vba, drop-down-menu

For some reason I am not being able to populate a dropdown box (html), here is part of my code:

```
ie.document.forms("ctl00_m_g_da21fae8_4ec1_4753_b9e0_4941851f566b_FormControl0").Item("V1_I1_S1_I1_D8").Value = "Seller"
ie.document.forms("ctl00_m_g_da21fae8_4ec1_4753_b9e0_4941851f566b_FormControl0").Item("V1_I1_S1_I1_D8").FireEvent ("onChange")
```

This is the part of html code for this dropdown from the webpage:

```
SELECT tabIndex=0 title="" 
class="ab_HZ54NFZpWLWUsncZ_0 ad_HZ54NFZpWLWUsncZ_0 he_HZ54NFZpWLWUsncZ_0 g5_HZ54NFZpWLWUsncZ_0"
id=ctl00_m_g_da21fae8_4ec1_4753_b9e0_4941851f566b_FormControl0_V1_I1_S1_I1_D8 
aria-invalid=false style="DIRECTION: ltr" 
onfocus="return (DropDownList.OnFocus(this, event));" 
onblur="return (DropDownList.OnBlur(this, event));" 
onchange="return (DropDownList.OnChange(this, event));" 
OriginalId="V1_I1_S1_I1_D8" FormId="ctl00_m_g_da21fae8_4ec1_4753_b9e0_4941851f566b_FormControl0"
ViewDataNode="16" direction="ltr" wrapped="true" ScriptClass="DropDownList">
  <OPTION value=""></OPTION>
  <OPTION value=CSR>CSR</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=Distributor>Distributor</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="Lab Tech" selected>Lab Tech</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=Manager>Manager</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=Seller>Seller</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=TS&amp;D>TS&amp;D</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=Others>Others</OPTION>
</SELECT>`
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try `ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_da21fae8_4ec1_4753_b9e0_4941851f566b_FormControl0_V1_I1_S1_I1_D8").selectedIndex = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_da21fae8_4ec1_4753_b9e0_4941851f566b_Form‌​Control0_V1_I1_S1_I1_D8").selectedIndex = 5`